# Parse JSON with unknown attributes names into a Case Class

Tags: json, scala, case-class

I have the following JSON file to be parsed into a case class:

```
{
    "root": {
        "nodes": [{
                "id": "1",
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "Node 1",
                    "size": "3"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "attributes": {
                    "value": "4",
                    "name": "Node 2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that the attributes could have any value inside it: name, size, value, anything ...

At this moment I have defined my case classes:

```
case class Attributes(
  name: String,
  size: String,
  value: Sting
)
case class Nodes(
  id: String,
  attributes: Attributes
)
case class Root(
  nodes: List[Nodes]
)
case class R00tJsonObject(
  root: Root
)
```

Whats is the best way to deal with this scenario when I can receive any attribute ?

Currently I am using Json4s to handle son files.

Thanks!

Comment: In that case why not just keep it as a map like Map[String, Any] or a `JObject` from Json4s?

Comment: Using classes allows me to create different methods to handle the data. I also need to modify data which is easier when using classes (Object are immutable)

Comment: There are immutable Maps in Scala and you can still create methods to handle the data if it's in a map.  You need to know what fields are going to be in your json in order to make it into a case class.  If they will vary you can always make them `Option` fields but you still need to know the name of the properties.

Comment: That's the case, I already have a case class with options. But I do not know the name for every property. I have this done with JObject, but I want to convert to case classes. I saw something about dynamic case classes, but is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attributes are arbitrarily many and differently named, but it seems you can store them in a `Map[String, String]` (at least, if those examples are anything to go by). In this case, using circe-parser (https://circe.github.io/circe/parsing.html), you could simply use code along these lines in order to convert your JSON directly into a simple case-class:

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

case class Node(id: String, attributes: Map[String,String])
case class Root(nodes: List[Node])

implicit val nodeDecoder: Decoder[Node] = deriveDecoder[Node]
implicit val nodeEncoder: Encoder[Node] = deriveEncoder[Node]

implicit val rootDecoder: Decoder[Root] = deriveDecoder[Root]
implicit val rootEncoder: Encoder[Root] = deriveEncoder[Root]

def myParse(jsonString: String) = {
  val res = parse(jsonString) match {
    case Right(json) => {
      val cursor = json.hcursor
      cursor.get[Root]("root")
    }
    case _ => Left("Wrong JSON!") 
  }
  println(res)
}
```

This snippet will print

```
Right(Root(List(Node(1,Map(name -> Node 1, size -> 3)), Node(2,Map(value -> 4, name -> Node 2)))))
```

on the console, for the JSON, you've given. (Assuming, the solution doesn't *have* to be in Json4s.)